# Add XSD attribute restriction

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="ItemBase" abstract="true">
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ContentItemBase" abstract="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="ItemBase">
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="path" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:attributeGroup name="path">
  <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  [...]
</xs:attributeGrou>

+ Various complex types derived from ContentItemBase, especially this one:
<xs:complexType name="FileItem">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="ContentItemBase">
      <xs:sequence>
        [...]
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

Now I want to add an attribute restriction on the "path" attribute BUT for FileItem only, not for other derived complex types of ContentItemBase.

How to add attribute restrictions to an attribute group which has been defined further up the complex type hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't extend and restrict in a single step. You need to define `FileItem0` as an extension of `ContentItemBase`, and then define `FileItem` as a restriction of `FileItem0`; you can restrict the attribute simply by re-declaring it with a new type, so long as the new type is a valid restriction of the base type.